# Pure CSS Thumbnail viewer, but problems with placement

Tags: css

I have a pure CSS image script I use with my eBay listings, I'm changing the design of my template at the moment and have run into a major snag with the code, it seems that the large image can only be displayed directly below the thumbnail radio buttons, but I want to have the large image being displayed in a different table cell..

I don't know a great deal about CSS, so hopefully someone will know an easy fix? here's hoping..

```css
<style type="text/css">
div.Image1BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image1_zpsus8mlxre.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image2BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image2_zpsetwycsgp.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image3BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image3_zpsxtx5woeg.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image4BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image5BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image1BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image1_zpsus8mlxre.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image2BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image2_zpsetwycsgp.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image3BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image3_zpsxtx5woeg.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image4BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image5BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }

section {
  display: none;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
label:hover {
  cursor: hand;
  border: 1px solid #1F7AB6;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #d0d0d0;
}
label {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
input:checked + label {
  border: 1px solid #155179;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #c0c0c0;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4,
#tab5:checked ~ #content5 {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table border=1><tr><td>
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1"><div class="Image1BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2"><div class="Image2BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3"><div class="Image3BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4"><div class="Image4BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5"><div class="Image5BlockS"></div></label>
  <section id="content1">
  <div class="Image1BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content2">
  <div class="Image2BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content3">
  <div class="Image3BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content4">
  <div class="Image4BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content5">
  <div class="Image5BlockB"></div>
  </section>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: When I try to put the elements which display the large image into another table cell they don't show up when the thumbnails are clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to rewrite it so that I can put the large image anywhere
>   throughout the template and still be able to have the small thumbnails
>   change it when they're clicked.

Well if this is the case then you can experiment with the [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

On the other hand you can imitate the `table` behavior with `display: table` and `td` with `display: table-cell` to get you closer to the desired result.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

div.Image1BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image1_zpsus8mlxre.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image2BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image2_zpsetwycsgp.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image3BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image3_zpsxtx5woeg.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image4BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image5BlockS { width:110px; height:92px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 110px 92px; }
div.Image1BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image1_zpsus8mlxre.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image2BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image2_zpsetwycsgp.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image3BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image3_zpsxtx5woeg.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image4BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image5BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }

div.Image4BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }
div.Image5BlockB { width:600px; height:500px; background-image:url('https://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u409/magneato1/image4_zpsixuqksa5.jpg'); background-size: 600px 500px; }

#table {
  display: table; /* imitates the table behavior */
  border: 1px solid;
  border: 1px outset grey;
  padding: 1px;
}

.table-cell {
  margin: 1;
  border: thin inset grey;
  display: table-cell;
}

section {
  display: none;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: hand;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}

label {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

input:checked + label {
  border: 1px solid #155179;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #c0c0c0;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4,
#tab5:checked ~ #content5 {
  display: table-cell; /* imitates the td behavior */
  border: thin inset grey;
  margin: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
      <label for="tab1"><div class="Image1BlockS"></div></label>

      <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab2"><div class="Image2BlockS"></div></label>

      <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab3"><div class="Image3BlockS"></div></label>

      <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab4"><div class="Image4BlockS"></div></label>

      <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab5"><div class="Image5BlockS"></div></label>
    </td>
    
    <div class="table-cell">
      2nd cell
    </div>
    
    <td>
      3rd cell with the td element but without the border which doesn't work if there's no table element
    </td>
    
    <div class="table-cell">
      4th cell
    </div>
    
      <section id="content1">
        <div class="Image1BlockB"></div>
      </section>

      <section id="content2">
        <div class="Image2BlockB"></div>
      </section>

      <section id="content3">
        <div class="Image3BlockB"></div>
      </section>

      <section id="content4">
        <div class="Image4BlockB"></div>
      </section>

      <section id="content5">
        <div class="Image5BlockB"></div>
      </section>
  
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what I want to do, but putting the large image elements into another cell breaks it, the large image no longer shows up, I need to rewrite it so that I can put the large image anywhere throughout the template and still be able to have the small thumbnails change it when they're clicked on.

```html
<table border=1><tr><td>
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1"><div class="Image1BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2"><div class="Image2BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3"><div class="Image3BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4"><div class="Image4BlockS"></div></label>
  <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5"><div class="Image5BlockS"></div></label>
</td>

<td>
  <section id="content1">
  <div class="Image1BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content2">
  <div class="Image2BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content3">
  <div class="Image3BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content4">
  <div class="Image4BlockB"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="content5">
  <div class="Image5BlockB"></div>
  </section>
</td>
</tr></table>
```